# Insert a variable into Import-Csv

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I am writing a PowerShell script to `Import-Csv`, then find a column with a key word, then `Export-Csv`. I have to have this script run for any file ending in *.csv in a folder. I cannot find a way to make a variable embedded into `Import-Csv`/`Export-Csv`. I can only make it work with a specific file name.

Here's what I've written:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Desktop\Rename\test.csv' |
    Where {$_.objectname -match "project" -and $_.objectname -ne "project code"} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Desktop\Rename\New.csv' -NoTypeInfo
```

I need to replace `C:\Users\Desktop\Rename\test.csv` to a `(variable).csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$CSVFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Desktop\Rename -Filter *.csv
Foreach ($CSV in $CSVFiles)
{
Import-Csv $CSV.FullName | Where {$_.objectname -match "project" -and $_.objectname -ne "project code"} | Export-Csv "C:\Users\Desktop\Rename\$($CSV.Name)_New.csv" -notypeinfo
}
```

Is that what you mean?